# Using cannon.js for collision detection in a three.js game

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision, physijs, cannon.js

I'm working on something with three.js where i need a way to handle collisions between objects very generally. I was thinking of using cannon.js since it supports the primitives i need but i don't always particularly need/want any of the overhead of the physics (lets say for detecting a bullet hitting a particular enemy), i just mainly want to use it for collision detection in a lot of cases since im not interested in going down the rabbit hole of writing my own general collision detection engine.

Basically what i'm asking is if there's a relatively simple way to use cannon.js, or perhaps some other javascript physics library to test for object/object object/terrain collisions and determine if objects are/aren't colliding. If i could get stuff like penetration depth, the normal of the collision etc. that would be even better.

would i be better off using physijs if i really wanted things to be tightly and effeciently integrated with my three.js code? it seems to also have what i need, but the performance seemed pretty bad from the demos on its main page.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The developper, Chanderprall (think I got that right) made Physijs an easy-to-use plugin for physics with THREE. He built it on top of `ammo.js` and **does** have an experimental `cannon.js` branch (unfortunatly only supports primitive shapes for now) which I guess works like the normal one.
 Personally, I think the entire library should only be used when you are dealing with real-time physics, where objects have dynamic positions, etc. If you simply wanted some collision detections without a physics engine, just use the `THREE.Raycaster`, which can detect if meshes (calculated using their bounding boxes) are intersecting using the `intersectObjects` method. You could quickly adapt it to detect how far an object went inside another object with some clever code.

http://webmaestro.fr/collisions-detection-three-js-raycasting/